# XML submissions in PHP rejected because missing matching end tags of data within an element. How to handle?

Tags: php, xml

I'm using XML to pass through raw HTML into a 3rd party API.

After submission I often receive errors such `<br>`, `<img>` and `<p>` `be terminated by the matching end-tag`. I don't care for the HTML to be perfect but apparently XML is overly sensitive and requires end-tags on everything.

I don't control the info that I'm sending over. What is the best way to deal with this? Is there any suggested script that could auto-insert end tags or is there a way for XML to ignore this error?

Thank you.

Comment: try using a cdata section?

Comment: How would cdata work? Say the element is `<data`>. Would I do `<data>![CDATA[.....html....]]></data>`

Comment: Yes, that should work, though you'll have to check whether the receiving api can handle a cdata section at this point.

Comment: Yup, works perfectly. Thanks. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how your xml is being generated but you could use htmlspecialchars